# Totally Weird Simple php execution - (can enyone explain[ it took me 4 hours to track down])

Tags: php, mysql, count

So i have a looooong php script and when the script executed it made two of my codeline`s Twice ! the one was and sql update in db and the other one was a Count mechanism as shown below. The cause of the error was that early in the script i had a html img tag with question mark in src.

php script that Counts twice.

```
<?
session_start();
print "<img src='?'>";
print "counter: ".count($_SESSION['Updated']);
if(!$_SESSION['Updated'])$_SESSION['Updated']= array();
$_SESSION['Updated'][] = "test";
?>
```

php script that Counts ones:

```
<?
session_start();
print "<img src=''>";
print "counter: ".count($_SESSION['Updated']);
if(!$_SESSION['Updated'])$_SESSION['Updated']= array();
$_SESSION['Updated'][] = "test";
?>
```

Can enyone explain, why php is running the codeline twice when the img src has and question mark in it ? 
IF i remove the question mark from the src tag everything runs normal.

Comment: PHP does not "run  code lines twice", certainly not. Most likely that question mark causes a second http request to the same script which results in a second execution. You should be able to verify that 1. in your http servers access log file and 2. in your browser network console.

Comment: Notice that the print "counter:..... line only appers once...... but the session Count (and array data) is increased with two on every page refresh......

Comment: Which is exactly one would expect with two separate executions, since in a single execution obviously each run executes each line only once. You _did_ understand what I wrote in my first comment?

Comment: how can i check if that is what happens ? 
I do not have acces to server access log file. (im on a payed webhotel)

Comment: I wrote above: "and 2. in your browser network console"

Comment: Apart from that: if your service provider _really_ does not offer any form of access to your http servers log files (access and error), then you should change the provider. _You cannot program php in a web environment without the ability to monitor the log files!_

Comment: I will keep that in mind - Thanks for you knowHow

Comment: You are welcome, have fun! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can. Browser is making first request to fetch your php script and second request to fetch image at URL:
Request URL:http://www.rchobbyworld.dk/test2.php?

(note ? at the end of URL). Hence your counter increases 2 times. You can see it with any web developer tools in a browser.

Comment: You Guys are absolutely genius !!! 
(I did`t know how to use the browsers develeper tools before this question)